# What enchantments can I use in the nether?

Tags: xbox-360, minecraft-legacy-console

What enchantments do I need to use in the Nether to collect all the potion ingridients like ghast tears and others in a really efficient way. Even if I get a potion of strength and fire resistance , ghast fire balls and the wither effect take me down.

Comment: You don't 'need' any enchants. All you need is something to kill the ghosts and blazes with.

Answer (score 2):

None are really needed, but if you want to be able to kill ghasts and such faster, you can do the following:

Enchant a Bow with power (For Ghasts)
Enchant a sword with sharpness and/or knockback (For Blazes and ground creatures)

These should make it a little faster. If you want to make it an even faster process, you can give yourself a strength potion to increase attack damage or a speed potion so you can move around quicker.

Hope I could help,

-Nick

Comment: Keep in mind that all mobs in the neteher are resistant to fire exept the overworld sketetons...

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you for the edit. I will change that now! @Janjak49